# Dev Tool to go over changes in the HTML

Tags: javascript, html, browser

When I use JS to alter classes in my HTML or when I remove or introduce elements, I find it hard to debug.  Sometimes elements or classes are only used for a fraction of a second and sometimes you I use many. For example, when I use [React Transition Group](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/).

Is there any tool to go through the different phases or changes in my HTML so I can see what an element looks like at a point in time? In Firefox this can be done with CSS animations, but I cannot find a tool for HTML changes.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic for SO

Answer (score 1):

you can try 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/WebReplay

Replay allows Firefox content processes to record their behavior, replay it later, and rewind to earlier states.  Replaying processes preserve all the same JS behavior, DOM structures, graphical updates, and most other behaviors that occurred while recording.  DevTools' Debugger and Console can be used to inspect and control the replay.

Comment: This looks great. Unfortunately currently only for macOS.